# Why I have to "source vitrualenvwrapper.sh" every time I open a new Terminal?

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, zsh

I use Zsh as my shell and I want to use vitrualenvwrapper. But when I close a terminal then open a new one, I have to "source virtualenvwrapper.sh" again then I can use virtualenvwrapper.

```
# koen @ Evan in ~ [10:59:12] 
$ lsvirtualenv
zsh: command not found: lsvirtualenv

# koen @ Evan in ~ [10:59:31] C:127
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 

# koen @ Evan in ~ [10:59:55] 
$ lsvirtualenv                              
Flask_env
=========


hello_env
=========



# koen @ Evan in ~ [11:00:08] 
$
```

Comment: Because you didn't put `source virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.zshrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your script `source`-ing in some shell session initialization file e.g. `/etc/zsh/zshrc` (global) or `~/.zshrc` (user-specific) will be read by `zsh` upon starting of an interactive session, with the latter one taking precedence over the former.

So, in your case, you can simple put the `source`-ing in `~/.zshrc` so that it would be read by `zsh` upon starting of the interactive session:

```
echo 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >>~/.zshrc
```